# How to restrict login access to website for mobile devices using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mobile, authentication, admin

I'm working on Codeigniter Application Framework where I want to disable login access for each user except admin on mobile devices only not on the desktop?

I have tried user agent library in my controller but users are still login through mobile devices?

When I added `&& !$this->agent->is_mobile()` in `if condition` then users are still login through mobile devices?

But I want login should work for users and admin on desktop and admin can only login on mobile devices?

**Here Controller**

```
public function __construct()
 {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('session');
       $this->load->library('user_agent');

 }

 public function login() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('iusername', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ipassword', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $Return = array('result'=>'', 'error'=>'');

    $username = $this->input->post('iusername');
    $password = $this->input->post('ipassword');

    $Return = array('result'=>'', 'error'=>'');

    /* Server side PHP input validation */
    if($username==='') {
        $Return['error'] = "Username field is required.";
    } elseif($password===''){
        $Return['error'] = "Password field is required.";
    }
    if($Return['error']!=''){
        $this->output($Return);
    }
    $allowlist = array(
        '192.168.6.6',

    );

    $data = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    );

    $result .= $this->Login_model->read_user_information($username);
    $checkusername = $result[0]->username;

    if ($result == TRUE) {

    if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$allowlist) 
    && $checkusername != 'admin' && !$this->agent->is_mobile()){
         $Return['error'] = 'This login cannot be accessed from your location.';    
         $this->output($Return);    
    } 
    else {

            // Add user data in session
            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $session_data);
            $Return['result'] = 'Logged In Successfully.
            $this->output($Return);
        }   
        } else {
            $Return['error'] = "Invalid Login Credential.";
            /*Return*/
            $this->output($Return);
        }

    }
```

**problem has been fixed**

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&& $this->mobiledetection->isMobile()` instead of `&& !$this->mobiledetection->isMobile()`?  You want to give the error when _not_ admin _and is_ mobile, right?  Also, you have a semicolon right after that that I'm pretty sure shouldn't be there.

Comment: i can't get you?

Comment: library is not loading properly??

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you're not able to communicate more clearly, I don't think I'm going to be able to help more than what I've already said.

Comment: you can spoof the user agent. even if you get this to work, its not 100% reliable

Comment: Any other solution??

Answer (score 0):

There is the issue in your if condition. update your condition by following codes

```
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$allowlist) && $username == 'admin' && !$this->agent->is_mobile()){
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $session_data);
    $Return['result'] = 'Logged In Successfully'.
    $this->output($Return);
}else {
    $Return['error'] = 'This login cannot be accessed from your location.';    
    $this->output($Return);    
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method but still, users can log in from mobile devices? it will work `!$this->agent->is_mobile('Android') ??`

Comment: @edgematrix, i have updated the answer, now check it,

Comment: no, i have updated the if condition... replace your condition by provided all codes

Comment: users still can log in can we use unset or destroy session ??

Comment: you can use both, but if you use destroy all session will be deleted.

Comment: What should other way to do it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169455/discussion-between-edgematrix-and-anfath-hifans).

Comment: please submit your answer I can't find it

Comment: Yes I have tried your code bit still usrrs can login through mobile devices